# How do I grow strawberries from seed?

Tags: seeds, germination, strawberries, optimal-conditions

I'm [thinking about](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14617/how-can-i-save-seeds-from-strawberries) saving my own strawberry seeds. I have some questions about the ideal conditions for optimal germination:

1. What soil/mix is best?
2. How deep should they be planted?
3. What is the best temperature for germination?
4. should they be germinated in the dark or under lighting?
5. How long until they germinate?
6. How long under optimal conditions should I expect to reach the three-leaf stage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is from my own experience rather than anything scientific but this seems to work well for me.

1. Any loamy potting soil mix - it must be fairly nutrient rich for best results and you may need to take care not to overwater
2. Very shallow, best to press into the soil gently with a finger and sprinkle a thin layer on top
3. Anything between 5 degrees celsius and 15 has worked but they seem to do best if started in a cooler environment then warmed up slightly as they grow.
4. I start them off in slightly dim light then move them to better lighting once they have formed leaves. They will germinate in very low light but the more light you can give them the better they seem to grow.
5. My results have varied from roughly 1 to 3 weeks before I see anything on the surface
6. Normally this happens 1 or two weeks after I notice them break the surface